# Deployment to Remote Machine failed - UWP Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am currently attempting to deploy an app to a Windows 10 tablet running the Creator's Update, over my local network. When I select remote machine and enter my debug settings, I can discover the tablet on my network, and get its address and Authentication mode automatically.

However, when I try to deploy, I get this error:

> DEP6957 : Failed to connect to device  using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. 0x8007274C: The network event being waited on triggered an error.

As far as I can tell from the documentation that I've read, this process should be more or less plug and play since the Creator's Update, can anyone explain what I might be doing wrong, or what might be going wrong?

Listed here are my debug settings currently in use.
[image: Debug Settings]

Update: Since its not the solution I was looking for, I'm not adding it as an answer, but if anyone comes across this looking for a fix and no one has suggested one, the way I ended up working through this is just downloading the remote debugger to the tablet and running the old method for C# apps. I never did find out why the UWP method didn't work.

Comment: Have you [Enable your device for development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)?What's your VS detail version? Could you please upgrade your Visual Studio and windows 10 tool and try again?

Comment: Both devices are enabled for development. I am currently using Visual Studio Professional 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. The PC was only built less than 2 weeks ago, and I recently ran the installer to add extra components.

Funnily enough, I can connect to the tablet using the older method with the Visual Studio Remote Debugging tools, but I'd also like to know what exactly is stopping me from doing it this way too.